# How do I plan a trip on europe effeciently

Tags: international-travel, europe, planning, tips-and-tricks, accommodation

I have 11 days to tour Europe.

My entry point is Berlin 24th Dec 2019 and my exit point from Europe is  Paris 3rd January 2019 and I haven't booked anything else including other travel tickets and accommodation.

As of now my trip plan is to visit Berlin followed by Munich, Salisburgh and Paris.

Please feel free to suggest me alternative trip plans.

I would like to make a day plan for every day with list of places and I would like to order it to make sure I'm covering all the places in shortest distance so that I'm using my time effectively.

When I'm travelling from one city to another I would like to stop over and visit some popular towns or cities in between.

Any suggestions or any tool which will help me with this ?

I would like to book my accommodation and travel ticket in an economical way. Any suggestions please.

Are there any other things I should be aware of when visiting these places?

Any suggestions to show some light is appreciated !

Comment: The first thing I’d do is check what attractions, restaurants etc are actually open on Christmas Day and New Year’s Day in the locations where you’ll be in those dates. You may find it difficult to get economical travel and accommodation bookings over this period at such short notice. I’d consider reducing the number of intended locations to visit - you’ll find yourself spending more time travelling than actually experiencing these wonderful places.

Comment: Any tips and tricks to cut down the total expenses ?

Comment: Yes - consider changing your travel dates into the new year :-)

Comment: By "Salisburgh", do you mean Salzburg, Austria; the birthplace of Mozart, or Salisbury, UK, with its tallest church spire in England and where Russian agents murdered Sergei Skripal in 2018?  They are a long way apart.

Comment: This is too broad, opinion-based and [We Are Not Travel Agents](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents). VTC.

Comment: @Traveller - Salzburgh,Austria

Comment: Regarding expenses: Accomodation will be expensive in and close to the alps because of winter tourism. To visit Salzburg, I'd suggest a day trip from Munich by train. Also, consider smaller cities like Rothenburg ob der Tauber.

Comment: Oh That's great ! How about accommodation at Munich ? Is it expensive ?

Comment: You might ask a question on this site: "How to find cheap accomodation in Germany?" if there isn't already one about this topic. For starters, try booking.com etc.

Comment: @user24582 - I have raised a new question for that. thanks

Comment: A few attractions in the Munich area: Schloss Neuschwanstein, Zugspitze, Chiemsee islands (Herrenchiemsee, Frauenchiemsee), Partnachklamm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a couple of comments mentioned, the big problem will be what is open over Christmas and New Year.  Throughout Europe, this is a time of restricted travel options and restricted opening of attractions, restaurants, and hotels booked up months in advance.

The other problem I see, is trying to do too much over a short time.  Four cities, with a day of travel between each of them, in just 11 days, won't leave you with much time for sightseeing or for stopping off to see somewhere else on he way. And bad weather (snow/ice) might make travel even slower.

Even so, assuming you are travelling mostly by train or rental car, here are some suggestions on what you could see between cities if you can stretch your plan:

Berlin - Munich: Stop off in Leipzig, Nuremburg and maybe Regensburg.

Munich - Salzburg: Not much to see on the way, but Hitler's Eagle's Nest mountain retreat is south of Salzburg if that's the kind of thing you want to see.

If instead you meant Salisbury, UK:  It is a long drive/train from Munich - you would be better off flying to London, then train to Salisbury.  But once in London, there is a lot more to see there.

From Salzburg to Paris is a long day by train, or a non-stop 11 hours by car.  Once again it is best to fly, but Salzburg's small airport doesn't have a direct flight to Paris, it might be better driving back to the much bigger airport in Munich.  If you do go by land, you could stop off in Ulm and Epernay, or go via Switzerland (though in mid-winter mountain passes might be closed so you will be restricted to major highways which tend to stick to the flatter parts of Switzerland).

To be honest though, there is enough to see in either Berlin or Paris to occupy a week or more.

Comment: Hi Nick ! Thanks for answering. When I travel from Salzburgh to Paris. I don't want to directly go to paris. Is there any small beautiful towns and cities on the way to paris so that I can spend some time over there.